# Reverse current protection

Tags: protection, reverse-polarity, waterproof

I design a wearable, battery-powered device with a watertight enclosure. It will have a waterproof USB connector for battery charging. Here is a schematic.
[image: Voltage regulation and battery charging]

J2 is the USB connector, MCP73831 is the battery charger and U8 is a step-down buck converter. Do I need an additional reverse current protection here in case the device is immersed in water (maybe seawater) when VBUS and GND USB pins will be short-circuited or connected through some resistance?

I believe that MCP73831 has some, but not sure.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Well, in most project we don't take mitigation against immersion through electronics.  Most damage is exposure to salty water + time, and once the water is in, I am wondering whether failing fast is actually is a bad thing.

Comment: Actually Samsung was able to measure impedance between USB connector pins and tell me that the USB port is likely wet, and I should dry it. Never investigated how.

Comment: But my thought is that reverse polarity is not an issue, exposing the battery to 5V is unlikely an issue due to it being a high impedance connection.

Comment: In my case the device should work as long as possible on one battery’s charge. Even it will be damaged by water.

Comment: Then I would check conformal coating.